# Pig MR job failing when run by same user who started the cluster

Tags: hadoop, permissions, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am seeing this exception intermittently for some mappers and reducers in my Pig map reduce job. Most of the times it is retried on some other node and the task succeeds. But sometimes all 4 tasks fails and the map reduce job fails.

However the interesting thing is the folder jobcache indeed has permissions 700. I dont understand why it is not able to create the folder inside it.

```
Error initializing attempt_201212101828_0396_m_000028_0:
java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: /apollo/env/TrafficAnalyticsHadoop/var/hadoop/mapred/local_data/taskTracker/trafanly/jobcache/job_201212101828_0396 to 0700
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:682)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobLocalizer.createJobDirs(JobLocalizer.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DefaultTaskController.initializeJob(DefaultTaskController.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$4.run(TaskTracker.java:1226)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$5.run(TaskTracker.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I am using Hadoop 1.0.1 if that helps. One more thing which i found while searching online was: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-890. **In my case the user who started the mapred cluster is indeed running the job and that is when it fails. For any other user the job runs just fine.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

change the permissions of the directories you have used as property values in your .xml configuration files to 755